# strech two lines to same length?

Tags: css

I would like to reproduce the following image with CSS:

[image]

Especially important is to me that both lines have equal length:

[image]

I tried to recreate it with this code ([jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47oc0qfv/)):

```css
.box {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #2c343c;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.box .name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.box .sub {
  color: #f29400;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
  <span class="name">Dr. Nielsen</span><br>
  <span class="sub">WEBDEVELOPER
 </div>
```

But its not quite perfect:

[image]

Is there a good way how to achieve this with CSS so that both lines get the same lengths on any device. Or is it recommended to rather use a picture for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "lines"?

Comment: @Rob I mean that "Dr. Nielsen" should have the same length as "Webdeveloper". How would you phrase the question title more accurate?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean left & right padding? Have you considered just making an svg of this logo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a try to `text-align-last:justify;`

Beside, to avoid setting a width, you may turn the box into a block that shrinks on its content via `display:table;` . You can also avoid the `<br>` setting spans into blocks

```css
.box {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #2c343c;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: table;
  text-align: justify;
}

span {
  display: block;
  text-align-last: justify;
}

.box .name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.box .sub {
  color: #f29400;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
  <span class="name">Dr. Nielsen</span>
  <span class="sub">WEBDEVELOPER</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span class="name">Dr. Nielsen</span>
  <span class="sub">WEB-DEVELOPPER</span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span class="name">Watch Out when top too long</span>
  <span class="sub">single-short-breaks!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: As long as the below string is longer, this will work on any device with any resolution right?

Comment: @Adam Yes, that is idea.text-align-last:justify will take care of it. A single word on the other side will not be stretch

Comment: I have read in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last) that `text-align-last` only effects the last line of a block. Since `span` is a block I would expect that we should get the same outcome if we use `text-align:justify` on span instead. But its not the same outcome? Could you explain that? Trying to understand why your code actually works.

Comment: @Adam When you have a single line, it is also the last. The span are also displyed here as blocks, so text-align-last is usable ;)

Comment: I agree when you have a single line that this is the last. Thats why I would expect that there should be no difference in using `text-align` and `text-align-last` on the span, because it only has one line. But there seems to be a difference. But maybe I should create a new question for that, might be too complicated to explain that in the comments.

Comment: text-align:justify is not applied on the last or a single line , default alignement turns to be left or right (language direction) . This is why text-align-last is required to trigger justify on that single line . ;) What is bothering you here is the width of box set by the longest element . webdevelloper span is longer and sets the width. the first span as a block will use that width too. text-align-last can, from there, spray words from one side to the other. (add borders to span to see them and reset width to box to see ext-align-last in action)

Comment: Perfect I understand it now. Thank you for your explanation. I noticed also that the "Dr." has a little margin to its left, so it does not start exactly at the 'W' but thats okay with me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `text-align: justify;` on the container (`.box`) and give `.name` some extra letter-spacing so the 2 lines line up.

> Be aware that this would be completely dependent on the font settings. Another font-family, size, etc. would change the size of both lines and make it different again. If people visiting your website changed their browser font size, then they won't see exactly what you see. If you want to avoid this (as much as possible) then look into *font-size resets*.

```css
.box {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #2c343c;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}

.box .name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: .3px;
  /* added */
}

.box .sub {
  color: #f29400;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
  <span class="name">Dr. Nielsen</span>
  <span class="sub">WEBDEVELOPER</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice.. I did not know letter space accepts decimal values. Will this work for different devices with different resolutions?

Comment: @Adam Be warned, I've seen different browsers produce different results even on the same computer, using the same font etc. If it's important that everything looks pixel perfect, use a graphic.